# Trello Board says "You have too many lists"

Tags: trello, list

I am getting an error when going to the end of my board and trying to add a list. Where you would normally click to add a list, it says "You have too many lists" but there are only 15 open lists. I have even tried deleting archived lists which does not fix the error. Please advise.